# Stacking UIkit.modal built-in dialogs

Tags: javascript, html, getuikit

UIkit has built-in [helper dialogs](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#modal-dialogs) like *confirm*. Which is great but by default UIkit modals replace all other modals when shown. This behaviour can be changed with the `stack` [option](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#component-options) as long as I am defining the modal dialog - but this is not the case with the built-in ones. I have found a [snippet](https://codepen.io/aarongerig/pen/EWbOwJ) on how to change their labels.

But how can I make the built-in helper modal to be stacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have found a solution: https://codepen.io/zorgoz/pen/pOZRyP

`UIkit.modal.confirm('My message!', {stack: true,...})` seem to work.